# Deducting cpu type from dumped machine language

Tags: assembly, reverse-engineering

I have the motherboard from an office copying machine, and I'm dumping it's roms to try and figure it out (it has, like, atleast 3 seperate microcontrollers! It's WEIRD!)

I have the rom dumped (well, the first 32 bytes, I don't have a rom programmer...), and it looks like machine code.

How do I figure out what TYPE of machine code this is? Just, slap it in various decompilers and choose the one that "makes the most sense"? Surely there's a more efficient way.

Comment: The first 32 bytes of a ROM might well not be machine code, it might be data.  The entry point might be near the end.  If it is machine code, 32 bytes might be enough to rule out some ISAs as implausible, but it might be hard to be sure.

Comment: This question about reverse-engineering techniques (which aren't also programming techniques) is probably on topic on https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/, but might not be here on SO.

Comment: Can't you tell by looking at those microcontrollers and using google what type they are?

Comment: Good point on the 32 bytes thing.

Comment: Half of them, yes, but the main processor is a "black label" job with meaningless part numbers etched on it.